# Can I add JSON and Form data to a post request using OkHTTP?

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I wonder is it possible to send a POST request that contains json payload and also some form data using OkHTTP.

Sending Form Data:

```kotlin
var requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
requestBody.addFormDataPart(k, v.toString())

request.url(urlBuilder.build().toString()).post(requestBody.build()).build()
```

Sending JSON payload:

```kotlin
var jsonRequestBody = json.toString().toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())

request.url(urlBuilder.build().toString()).post(jsonRequestBody).build()
```

I can only send a single requestbody with the post request, I wonder is there a way to combine both form and json requestbody?

Comment: Of course. Add json as FormDataPart.

Comment: I want to send both of them separately, like in Python requests module. `requests.post(url, data={}, json={})`

Comment: Well they are separated then i would say.